# Proxy aware or DNS capable meterpreter?

Tags: dns, proxy, meterpreter

I'm having issues traversing a proxy protected network and was wondering if there are meterpreter implementations which allow proxy awareness (automatically using windows AD credentials) or which can use DNS tunneling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meterpreter bind or reverse http and https support web proxies transparently. The reason is that both uses the WinInet API for accessing the Internet and the API takes care of the proxy authentication. By default meterpreter http(s) support only NTLM authentication for the proxy. If you are dealing with a proxy that is using basic authentication, you can use [Meterpreter with basic authentication suppport](http://funoverip.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/reverse_https_proxy_basicauth.tar.gz). It hasn't been merged in the main msf tree but you can add it to the modules tree manually.

Comment: Tried that one didn't work at first, turns out the IP I was connecting back to  was blacklisted by the protective proxy. ><